# Making dynamic layout for each row in ListView in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a xml file which contains basic layout for each row of ListView(which is a realtive layout and has TextView inside it).

I want to change the attributes of this layout for each row of ListView like different layout width and height of each row. I want to set the values of width and height dynamically.

Is there any way around to do this?

My xml file which I want to change, height and weight dynamically, for each view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="text"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF200010"
        android:background="#FFFCCCFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my full file is

```
package com.test.list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MultipleItemsList extends ListActivity {

    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

    public Context context =getApplicationContext();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
        for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
            mAdapter.addItem("item " + i);
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("separator " + i);
            }
        }
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

        private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

        public MyCustomAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            // save separator position
            mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1,null);
                            Log.e("Ronak", "Here1");
                            TextView t= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                            t.setWidth(100);
                            t.setHeight(600);
                            t.setText("This is first type of view");
                            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                            Log.e("Ronak","reached here3");
                            break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:

                          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                          TextView t2= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                            t2.setWidth(200);
                            t2.setHeight(500);
                            t2.setText("This is second type of view");
                          holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                          break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your existing code ?

Comment: @FaisalAli I have added my layout file

Comment: Note that you should change the relative params to `wrap_content` and change the `with` and `height` of the text view dynamically

Comment: @Arkde I changed my getView() function as what you said but my program is crashing. Can you help me out

Comment: I saw the problem. The problem is the way you are using `findViewById`. First you have to do the `convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2,null);` to inflate the xml structure into your `convertView` and you should use `findViewById` on that view `TextView t2= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);`

Comment: @Arkde I am sorry but my app is still crashing. Can you please help me out. I have updated my file and posted the file above

Comment: Remove this line `public Context context =getApplicationContext();` you are not using it anyway. And take care when you choose to initialize a field like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a `ViewHolder` pattern for your adapter, and for each position, inflate your own layout.

To do that, override `getView`  like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {            

   // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls            
  // to findViewById() on each row.            
  ViewHolder holder;            
  // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need            
  // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied            
  // by ListView is null.            

  if (convertView == null) {                

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);   
    // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views                
    // we want to bind data to.               
   holder = new ViewHolder();                
   holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);               
   holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);                
   convertView.setTag(holder);            
 } else {                
   // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView                
   // and the ImageView.
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }             


  // Bind the data efficiently with the holder. 
  holder.name.setText(myElements.get(id)); 
  holder.icon.setImageBitmap( mIcon1 );

return convertView;
}
```

Read more about this on the Android developer site [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

EDIT:

To change the width and height of each row, you can use something like the following, for each row on bind data section
:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourId); 
rl.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
rl.getLayoutParams().width = 100;`
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I want the layout width and height to set dynamically and want that **width and height** for that row of ListView.
I want to set width and height for each row. Can you further suggest how to do it?

Comment: I have edited my response to clarify how to set attributes grammatically

Comment: Can you tell me, where to put the above code in getView() beacuse when I did the exact same, its giving me RunTimeException

Comment: Let's say you have in your R.layout.sample, an xml that contains a RelativeLayout with id, `yourId` . In your `ViewHolder` you declare a RelativeLayout as field, and you have something like this : `holder.relative = (RelativeLayout) convertView. findViewById(R.id.yourId); `  . After that in your bind data section you will have `holder.relative.getLayoutParams().height = 100;` Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

> Making dynamic layout for each row in ListView in android

Maybe @Arkde's answer could work but i i think it's little dirty solution.

What about to create one **generic layout** and update / change appearance due to provided conditions? (for example due to value in current row).

> different layout width and height of each row

This can by easily achieved by an usage of "margins". By "margins" i think a creation of empty Views which will work as "margins" and will determine height of row for instance. And then due to mentioned condition(s) showing or hiding them<sup>1</sup>.

*What are advantages of generic layout?*

- Easier, efficient and more human-readable solution
- You don't need to implement ViewType and ViewCount for Adapter
- One layout for each row with changeable appearance
- You don't need to change UI appearance from application
  logic in "hardcoded" way

<sup>1</sup> When visibility of View is assigned to `View.GONE` it won't take place in layout whereas `View.VISIBLE` takes place.

**Example of "margin":**

```
<LinearLayout>
   ...
   <View 
      android:id="@+id/upperMargin"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   />

   ...

   <View 
      android:id="@+id/lowerMargin"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   />
   ...
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** Suggested an usage of ViewHolder is very neat and effective approach if you want to increase perfomance of `ListView`.

I hope that my solution will help to solve your problem you're facing now.