# Dynamically add rows (with dynamic content) to listview without XML inflation

Tags: java, android, listview

I am up to something a little different from the standard custom listviews. I am having an activity which is responsible for displaying data retrieved from Parse.com database. The data contents are mostly in html format and may have any amount of text and images.

**What I have already done:**

1. Retrieving the data from the database.
2. Putting the data in a linear layout which is dynamically created according to the contents of the html.

**What I wan to achieve:**

1. Add the layout to a listview as a row layout.

I have gone through a number of forums but I am still unable to find a solution using which I can inflate a listview without an xml layout and can assign my dynamic layout instead.

The **activity source code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ArrayList<String> originalContentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> reversedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ImageView imageView1;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    RelativeLayout parent_layout;

    ParseObject user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parent_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

        login("xxx@xxx.com", "xxx");

        // reverseArraylist();
    }


    private void loopThroughArrayAndAttach(){
        LinearLayout llInner = new LinearLayout(this);
        llInner.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        parent_layout.addView(llInner);
        for (int i = 0; i < originalContentList.size(); i++) {

            if (hasNoImagess(originalContentList.get(i)) == true) {
                // No images.
                TextView myText = geneterTextView(originalContentList.get(i));
                llInner.addView(myText);

            } else {
                ImageView myImage = geneterImageView(originalContentList.get(i));
                llInner.addView(myImage);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasNoImagess(String contents){
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(contents);
        Element element = doc.body();
        Elements elements = element.select("img");
        if (elements.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public ImageView geneterImageView(String imgContent){
        // Will need to run via background thread - like aysnc
        // Extract the image file via jsoup
        // Insert it into a imagevieww
        // Inser that into a layout.
        Log.d("IN IMAGE ", " " + imgContent);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(imgContent);
        Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = null;
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        for (Element el : img) {
            String src = el.absUrl("src");
            System.out.println("src attribute is : " + src);
            // new DownloadImageTask((ImageView)
            // findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).execute(src);
            try {
                //returnedBitmap = new LoadImage().execute(src).get();
                WorkerThread mWorkerThread = new WorkerThread(iv);
                mWorkerThread.execute(src);
                // imageView1.setImageBitmap(returnedBitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
//      ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageBitmap(returnedBitmap);
        return iv;
    }

    public TextView geneterTextView(String textContent){
        // Will need to run via background thread.
        Log.i("In TEXT ", " " + textContent);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(textContent));
        return tv;
    }


    private class WorkerThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
        private WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public WorkerThread(ImageView imageView) {
            super();
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
            // bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(args[0]).getContent());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null && imageViewReference.get() != null) {
                imageViewReference.get().setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }

    }

    // to login to parse
    private void login(final String username, String password){
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e){

                if (e == null) {
                    // if login sucess
                    // Start intent
                    // loginSuccess();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CloudCallStudentPosts(user);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    // //to get data from parse
    public void CloudCallStudentPosts(ParseObject s){

        setRichStory(s);
    }

    private void setRichStory(ParseObject s){
        // Simialr to setStory, once implemented delete setStory()
        new AddStoryAsync(s).execute();
    }

    class AddStoryAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Object, Void> {

        private static final String TAG = "LazyListView";
        ParseObject s;

        public AddStoryAsync(ParseObject s) {
            this.s = s;
            Log.w("In richStory", "ParseObject Id: " + s.getObjectId());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused){
            HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("userid", this.s.getObjectId());
            params.put("skip", 0);
            ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("studentsPosts", params, new FunctionCallback<List<List<ParseObject>>>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<List<ParseObject>> postList, com.parse.ParseException arg1){
                    if (postList == null) {
                    } else {
                        if (postList.size() > 0) {
                            // CustomWebView cwb;
                            for (int i = 0; i < postList.size(); i++) {
                                // final Post post = new Post();

                                if (postList.get(i).get(0).get("htmlContent") == null) {

                                    if (postList.get(i).get(0).getNumber("type") != null) {
                                        // post.setType(postList.get(i).get(0).getNumber("type"));
                                    }

                                    if (postList.get(i).get(0).getString("question") != null) {
                                        // post.setQuestion(postList.get(i).get(0).getString("question"));
                                    }

                                    if (postList.get(i).get(0).getString("textContent") != null) {
                                        // post.setQuestion(postList.get(i).get(0).getString("textContent"));
                                    }

                                    if (postList.get(i).get(0).getString("answer") != null) {
                                        // post.setAnswer(postList.get(i).get(0).getString("answer"));
                                    }

                                    if (postList.get(i).get(0).getCreatedAt() != null) {
                                        // post.setCreatedAt(postList.get(i).get(0).getCreatedAt());
                                    }

                                    // Need to re-get map and trip and photo
                                    // types
                                    if (postList.get(i).get(0).getParseFile("photo") != null)
                                        postList.get(i).get(0).getParseFile("photo").getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(byte[] imageByte, ParseException arg1){
                                                if (arg1 == null) {
                                                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByte, 0, imageByte.length);
                                                    if (bmp == null) {

                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }

                                        });

                                    if (postList.get(i).get(0).getJSONArray("tripPoints") != null) {
                                        // post.setTripPoints(postList.get(i).get(0).getJSONArray("tripPoints"));
                                    }

                                    if (postList.get(i).get(0).getParseGeoPoint("location") != null) {
                                        // post.setLocation(postList.get(i).get(0).getParseGeoPoint("location"));
                                    }

                                    // publishProgress(post);
                                }

                                if (postList.get(i).get(0).get("htmlContent") != null) {
                                    Log.e("htmlContent parse", postList.get(i).get(0).get("htmlContent").toString());
                                    // Parse HTML String using JSoup library
                                    String HTMLSTring = postList.get(i).get(0).get("htmlContent").toString();

                                    Document html = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring);

                                    Elements paragraphs = html.getElementsByTag("p");
                                    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element paragraph : paragraphs) {
                                        String paragraphText = paragraph.toString();
                                        Log.e("paragraphText", paragraphText);
                                        originalContentList.add(paragraphText);
                                    }

                                    loopThroughArrayAndAttach();
                                }
                                // publishProgress(post);
                                // This is where we publish

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
            return (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... object){

            Log.w("onProgressUpdate ", " " + object[0].getClass());

            Log.w("adding to arrayPostList ", " " + object[0].getClass());

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused){
        }

    }

}
```

The method `loopThroughArrayAndAttach()` is generating the `linearlayout` programmatically and adding imageviews and textviews to it dynamically. For now the  `linearlayout` is attached to the parent layout which, which needs to be substituted with a listview.

**The layout:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout">
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**How to achieve the desired output?**

Comment: `inflate a listview without an xml layout and can assign my dynamic layout instead.` you do not understand.  `inflate` means to parse the XML layout and create the view heirarchy.  All you need to do is `Listview myListView = new ListView(this)` or similar.  There is nothing magical and layout XML.  It is just data to describe to the inflater what objects to create and which properties to set.  See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897942/making-dynamic-layout-for-each-row-in-listview-in-android

Comment: @Simon I have gone through that post already but could not figure out what is to be done exactly. As I could see  convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);    and some other views with ids which are supposed to be predefined in the xml.