# how to make static expandabletextview to dynamic expandaletextview

Tags: android

I create a static expandaletextview in this example i used two Textview and two ImageButton so now how to i make this dynamic expandable..Any one can help me please because i m very new in android... Here below is my full static source code  thanks in advance

```
MainActivity class

package com.example.atextalignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     TextView descText;
     ImageButton show, hide;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      descText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_text);
      show = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.show);
      show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Show button");
        show.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        hide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        descText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

       }
      });
      hide = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.hide);
      hide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Hide button");
        hide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        descText.setMaxLines(5);

       }
      });

     }

    }
```

```css
my Xml layout

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.atextalignment.Second" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:text="@string/desc_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/hide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```css
String.xml

<string name="desc_content">     Android powers hundreds of millions of mobile devices in more than 190 countries around the world. It\'s the largest installed base of any mobile platform and growing fast—every day another million users power up their Android devices for the first time and start looking for apps, games, and other digital content.

Android gives you a world-class platform for creating apps and games for Android users everywhere, as well as an open marketplace for distributing to them instantly.
</string>
```

Comment: Which part you want to make dynamic?

Comment: i want to make textview part ...

Comment: You can create dynamic textview inside your adapter as per your need

Comment: i m very new in android so can edit my code... r u have any example please send me ....it's my humbly request...

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897942/making-dynamic-layout-for-each-row-in-listview-in-android). You can follow the second answer there. If you are facing problem in creating dynamic layout for child items better create a generic view and just shuffle that view to `View.GONE` when not needed.